# python PIL draw.text

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I was following this post: https://haptik.ai/tech/putting-text-on-images-using-python-part2/
However, every time I try to execute the example code:

```
text = "This could be a single line text but its too long to fit in one."
lines = text_wrap(text, font, image_size[0])
line_height = font.getsize('hg')[1]

x = 10
y = 20
for line in lines:
    # draw the line on the image
    draw.text((x, y), line, fill=color, font=font)
    # update the y position so that we can use it for next line
    y = y + line_height
# save the image
img.save('word2.png', optimize=True)
```

I get an error that name 'draw' is not defined on this line:

```
draw.text((x, y), line, fill=color, font=font)
```

I tried to change it to:

```
ImageDraw.Draw.text((x, y), line, fill=color, font=font)
```

as that what I believe the documentation specifies: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html

However, that did not work either.
So could someone help fix this error, because I'm not quite sure what's wrong. 
I'm using python 3 in VS Code if that's of any help

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

The problem was that a draw had not been defined like this:

```
image = Image.open(r'E:\me\Documents\code\assets\template.jpg')  #path to image

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
```